# How to track down which field is causing NullPointerException when inserting custom field into Contacts Data table?

Tags: java, android

The full exception I get is:

```
07-16 19:19:17.244: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(151): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 19:19:17.244: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(151):     at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.insertData(ContactsProvider2.java:3069)
07-16 19:19:17.244: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(151):     at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.insertInTransaction(ContactsProvider2.java:2930)
07-16 19:19:17.244: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(151):     at com.android.providers.contacts.CContactsProvider2.insertInTransaction(CContactsProvider2.java:156)
07-16 19:19:17.244: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(151):     at com.android.providers.contacts.HtcContactsProvider2.insertInTransaction(HtcContactsProvider2.java:1281)
07-16 19:19:17.244: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(151):     at com.android.providers.contacts.SQLiteContentProvider.insert(SQLiteContentProvider.java:90)
07-16 19:19:17.244: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(151):     at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.insert(ContactsProvider2.java:2737)
07-16 19:19:17.244: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(151):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:150)
07-16 19:19:17.244: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(151):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:170)
07-16 19:19:17.244: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(151):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:287)
07-16 19:19:17.244: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(151):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

The code I used is:

```
public void saveFormality() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Data.DATA1, this.getFormality() ? "1" : "0");
    saveDataWithMimeType(clsContacts.MIMETYPE_FORMALITY, values, this.getId());
}


private void saveDataWithMimeType(String mimetype, ContentValues values, String contactid) {
    try {
        int mod = ctx.getContentResolver().update(
                Data.CONTENT_URI,
                values,
                ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactid + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= '"
                        + mimetype + "'", null);

        if (mod == 0) {
            values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactid);
            values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, mimetype);
            // this is where exception occurs
            Uri u=ctx.getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This happens on the phone only, and not in the emulator. All fields were checked and none of them are nulls. What could be the cause?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to exception NullPointerException and debug the code

Comment: What API level is this happening on?

Comment: I've already tried that, but something happens internally in the content provider(that I have no access to it) and all I see is the exception I posted.

Comment: This must be some device specific bug, because in original Android source ContactsProvider2.java:3069 is not the method insertData().

Comment: If so, how can I do some workaround?

Comment: Does debugging show anything useful? What's your hardware?

Comment: No it doesn't. I run on a HTC Legend with SenseUI.

Answer (score 10):

Figured it out via an enormous process of poking around in the raw data for manually added contacts, followed by trial and error to figure out what data the content provider was insisting on having. It's simple enough:

When inserting a new phone record, you *must* specify a `Data.Type` (the column named "data2"). If you don't specify this, HTC's Contacts ContentProvider will crash with a NullPointerException. The stock Android Contacts ContentProvider doesn't crash, it simply defaults to TYPE_OTHER.

Damn and blast HTC for (a) implementing a different Contacts ContentProvider that does *not* play by the documented rules, and (b) for only releasing the kernel source code. We need **HtcContactsProvider2.java** to see what their code thinks the problem is.

Comment: Faced the same problem. Thank you for posting the solution here!

Comment: how to specify the type of data.?

Comment: I always pass CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, but People app still crashes on HTC One X, not sure what to do :(

Comment: problem still exists on android 4.x. thanks for solution, man!

Answer (score -1):

Split the line `ContactsProvider2.java:3069` into several which only contain a single dot. That way, the line number will match a single field dereference which will tell you directly which field is `null`.

Comment: Unfortunately that is inbuilt in the Android SDK system and I have no access to those.

Comment: Search your SDK for the source of this file and check the code.

Comment: As stated in the question this happens only on the phone, I don't have access to those files on the phone. Ognian told that it might be a device specific bug.

Comment: Try to open a bug report with the device manufacturer. Since the device shows line numbers, you can also try to download the class file and decompile it.