# NPE when inserting a contact to People app on HTC One in EntityModifier.getEntryCountByType()

Tags: android

The code that creates Insert intent is below

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "some name");
    final ArrayList<ContentValues> contactData = ...; // Populate array list here
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, contactData);
```

There is no problem running this code on Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 4, Nexus 7, Nexus 10.  But on HTC One People app crashes deep in HTC custom code:

```
06-30 13:34:57.589: E/AndroidRuntime(27942): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 13:34:57.589: E/AndroidRuntime(27942):    at com.android.htccontacts.model.EntityModifier.getEntryCountByType(EntityModifier.java:1056)
06-30 13:34:57.589: E/AndroidRuntime(27942):    at com.android.htccontacts.model.EntityModifier.isTypeAllowed(EntityModifier.java:1047)
06-30 13:34:57.589: E/AndroidRuntime(27942):    at com.android.htccontacts.model.EntityModifier.adjustType(EntityModifier.java:1003)
06-30 13:34:57.589: E/AndroidRuntime(27942):    at com.android.htccontacts.model.EntityModifier.parseValues(EntityModifier.java:942)
06-30 13:34:57.589: E/AndroidRuntime(27942):    at com.android.htccontacts.model.EntityModifier.parseExtras(EntityModifier.java:691)
06-30 13:34:57.589: E/AndroidRuntime(27942):    at com.android.htccontacts.ui.EditContactActivity2$AddContactTask.selectAccount(EditContactActivity2.java:5014)
06-30 13:34:57.589: E/AndroidRuntime(27942):    at com.android.htccontacts.ui.EditContactActivity2$AddContactTask.selectAccount(EditContactActivity2.java:4978)
06-30 13:34:57.589: E/AndroidRuntime(27942):    at com.android.htccontacts.ui.EditContactActivity2$AddContactTask.doInBackground(EditContactActivity2.java:4479)
06-30 13:34:57.589: E/AndroidRuntime(27942):    at com.android.htccontacts.ui.EditContactActivity2$AddContactTask.doInBackground(EditContactActivity2.java:4391)
06-30 13:34:57.589: E/AndroidRuntime(27942):    at com.android.htccontacts.util.WeakAsyncTask.doInBackground(WeakAsyncTask.java:45)
06-30 13:34:57.589: E/AndroidRuntime(27942):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-30 13:34:57.589: E/AndroidRuntime(27942):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

When I open People app after the crash, all inserted information is there.  All fields are correct, their types are also correct.  It is just annoying to see the crash in addition to not allowing the user edit the information before saving a new contact.

I've seen [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4387890/1224600), only my problem seems different: I always pass record type for every record.  And after the crash I can see the type I passed in the People app.

If somebody knows how to deal with this error in `EntityModifier.getEntryCountByType()`, could you please share your experiences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of NPE problem was that I was using the new method to insert contact records, based on [ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html#DATA) field.  HTC suggested looking at the code for `EntityModifier`.  Based on the stack trace, I thought it was HTC's code, but likely they just changed package name of [this code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/android-4.0.4_r2.1/src/com/android/contacts/model/EntityModifier.java), which has a bug in `getEntryCountByType`: `int size = entries.size();`  There are cases when `entries` can be null.

The bottom line is on older platforms instead of using `DATA` field to pass all records, I started using `PHONE`, `SECONDARY_PHONE` and other fields in [ContactsContract.Intents.Insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html).  This older method has limitations, but it does not crash People app on 4.0.x Android platforms.